# .env variable in cloudinary.config is not working

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I am implementing an upload file function and this is my cloudinary config:

**cloudinary.js**

```
cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME, 
  api_key: process.env.API_KEY, 
  api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
});
```

**.env**

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=auth
CLOUD_NAME=huabwxiwssd
API_KEY=7*************2
API_SECRET=A**************-**********I
```

(I do not want to reveal my api_key and api_secret so I use * to hide)
I installed dotend and config in server.js file
**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const route = require("./routes/ROUTES");
const db = require("./config/connectDB");
require("dotenv").config(); ------------------------> config here
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//Connect to database
db.connect();

//Run json in request.http
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Enable cors
app.use(cors());

//Routes init
route(app);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

It always shoots an error "**Must supply api_key**". I tried to search Stackoverflow to fix this issue like adding double quotes in variable in .env file but it doesn't work. I can only upload file successfully when I bind value directly in cloudinary.config but I don't want my key to be revealed. So, how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am implementing an upload file function and this is my cloudinary config:

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

// Config
dotenv.config();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
});

export default cloudinary;
```

Comment: yes, importing dotenv is solving my problem, but i don't know why we added it because i already added it on my server.js file